# Javascript how to make a loop to display ten division calculations without reminder

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script for kids to practice math. I managed to make +, -, x but can't complete divisions. Project can be seen here:
http://fibeeland.com/projects/math_tasks/index.html

I'm taking random numbers from the inputs and generate tasks. How to make division calculations so only examples with no reminder are shown?

my function looks like this:

```
//get a random number
function randomNumber(){
    var minNumberId = document.getElementById("minNrId");
    var xx=minNumberId.value;
    var maxNumberId = document.getElementById("maxNrId");                       
    var yy=maxNumberId.value;    
    var min = Math.ceil(xx);
    var max = Math.floor(yy);
    var randNr1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return randNr1;
}

function division(min,max,tasks){
    document.getElementById('division_loop').innerHTML = " ";
    var tasks_quantity = document.getElementById("tasks_quantity");
    var tasks = tasks_quantity.value;

        for (i=0; i < tasks; i++){
            var a = randomNumber();
            var b = randomNumber();

            if((a%b)===0){
                document.getElementById('division_loop').innerHTML += "<p><span class='task_punctuation'>" + (i+1) + ". </span>" + a + " / " + b +" = <input type='text' class='answerInput' id='" + (a/b) + "'></p>";
            } else{
                b = 2;
                document.getElementById('division_loop').innerHTML += "<p><span class='task_punctuation'>" + (i+1) + ". </span>" + a + " / " + b +" = <input type='text' class='answerInput' id='" + (a/b) + "'></p>";
            }



        }
    $(".answerInput").keyup(function() {
        var InputID = this.id;
        value = $(this).val();
        //change to lower case
        var InputIDlow = InputID.toLowerCase();
        var valuelow = value.toLowerCase();
        if(valuelow==InputIDlow){
            $(this).css('background-color', '#bcffb9');
        }
        else{
            $(this).css('background-color', '#dbdbf4');
        }
    }); 

    }

division();
```

Thank you in advance.
Matt

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a way to calculate factors, i.e. given a random number `a` you want to find `b` such that `a % b == 0`. Is that what you mean? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I get two random numbers from other function. I tried to use both and put them in the loop to keep looping till it finds a factor without reminder (Actually ten different examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay your script seems to work if a is divisible by `2`. You can check if that's the case and if not just add `1` to a.

That seems to be pretty boring for the kids :D

What about choosing a random number (just one)
For example `b = 3`

Then you can multiply that by a random number (you might wanna reduce the range so that the multiplication is within the bounds).

Then just say your result is `a` and then you just ask for `a/b`.

**Example**

```
b = randomNumber()
a = b*randomNumber() # adjusting the range
```

Then just as usually ask for `a/b`

Comment: I hardcoded 2 in else statement just to have some results. What I want is to put there a random number (b) but I need it to be without reminder.

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest solution. Not really what I wanted but it works so thank you :) I'll do it right one day when I become a Javascript ninja:)

Comment: @PhiCato easiest doesn't mean that it's bad. Is there a problem with my solution regarding your problem?

Comment: I hoped to find out the way of using modulus in this example. But, yes you're right. Your solution does the job and I get what I needed. Thank you Wikunia :)

Comment: You're welcome @PhiCato. Btw welcome at SO. Would you mind to upvote and accept the answer so that this question is marked as answered?

Comment: Can't upvote because of low reputation but I accepted the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @PhiCato thanx I know SO should change. Their system doesn't seem to work for newbies :(